401 Unauthorized when trying to fetch data from the DB
I'm building a React application where I'm trying to fetch the user profile data using a useEffect hook, but I keep encountering a "401 Unauthorized" error. Here's my code:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const Dashboard = () => {
  const [profile, setProfile] = useState({
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    email: '',
    phoneNumber: '',
    address: '',
    city: '',
    country: '',
    zip: '',
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProfile = async () => {
      const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
      if (!token) {
        console.error('No token found');
        return; // Handle the lack of token (redirect to login page or display a message)
      }
    
      try {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/user/profile', {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
        });
    
        if (response.ok) {
          const data = await response.json();
          setProfile(data); // Update the profile state with the fetched data
        } else {
          console.error('Failed to fetch profile:', response.status);
          // Handle unauthorized access, e.g., redirect to login page
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching profile:', error);
      }
    };
  
    fetchProfile();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Profile rendering logic */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;

I tried to fetch the user profile data from my backend API using the provided token for authentication. I expected the fetch request to return the user profile data successfully, updating the profile state with the fetched data.
However, despite having a valid token in the localStorage, the fetch request returned a "401 Unauthorized" error, indicating that the server rejected the request due to lack of authorization.

Seems your frontend and backend are on the same host localhost but might be on different port (extends to domain too) hence cors related issues.

Yeah so my backend is on 8000 and my frontend is on 5137
